# Passing a large amount of dynamic variables through a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I'm a research assistant, and currently in the process of building a webpage to open up a large sample of data sources for some researchers.

I have a sample of roughly 100.000 newspaper articles, that need to be accesible by a number of variables (source newspaper, date, content analysis tags, author, etc.). Currently I have a large form which generates a number of checkboxes for each of these variables, where users can select a subset of values for each variable to be listed on the target page. I built the form by using php arrays as input name tags, with the actual value as the value.

i.e.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='source[]' value='newspaperA'>
<input type='checkbox' name='source[]' value='newspaperB'>
```

and so forth. The real code does this dynamically, passing a checkbox for all options.

My problem is that this feels very inefficient. I'm passing a large amount of data through `$_POST`, and I just can't shake the feeling there should be a better option. So, long story short, is there? I'm relatively inept with javascript, and just recently started using jQuery. I feel like there's probably something there that I could use, but I honestly wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Passing user input data from a HTML form, Theres only the globals, Get, request and Post, unless you go the AJAX route.. If you don't like your storage placeholders, then I would suggest re-making your script.

Comment: An AJAX solution will send just as much data. Perhaps it is appropriate to examine the overall design of the app.

Comment: Given the architectural explanation of your app - there isn't. Which implies you should re-think your architecture.

Comment: if you only need to send indicator variables, define a total order on the options and add some javascript submit handler that aggregates the checkboxes into a bit sequence which you send to the server. an option's bit index should match its index in the pre-defined order. there are various method to implement checkboxes in the ui that are no form variables (easiest would probaby be to use 2 forms, one to submit data and another one as a container for the checkboxes  not having a submit button).

Comment: @collapsar; I like that, I was going to work with session variables and some ajax to allow for refinements of the results anyway, this should tie in nicely to that.

Comment: @N.B. This may be my inexperience speaking; but what would you suggest as far as architecture/design? I don't really see another way to provide the user with refinement options... Some pointers would be great :).

Comment: @Fluffy - well, how many options do you have to search the articles? There's too much info missing.